# OctoberCMS get list of content files

Tags: php, octobercms

Trying to get content files started with cont*

using :

`Content::loadCached('theme', 'listOfContentFiles');`

And getting an error.
I can get one but not the list.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: first using wildcard 'list*' getting  NULL. trying to enter array getting an error. 
i'm trying to get all files started with cont_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no direct way of doing it, you can use this code to get list manually and filter it by your self

```
use Cms\Classes\Content;
use Cms\Classes\Theme;

$activeTheme =  Theme::getActiveTheme();
$instance = Content::inTheme($activeTheme);

$items = $instance->newQuery()->lists('fileName');

$loadedItems = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {

    // we need to manually filter data you can
    // add more logic here for sub directory parsing etc
    if(starts_with($item, 'cont_')) {
        $loadedItems[] = Content::loadCached($activeTheme, $item);
    }
}

dd($loadedItems);

// if you want to make it collection
$result = $instance->newCollection($loadedItems);
```

it will return you list of content files in active theme by our filter logic.

Comment: Looks nice ? Please accept the answer if this solution works a) people with similar issue can use it b) the person helping you deserves a thumb up..
If it doesn't also say it did not work,

Comment: its wired, that there no bulidin solution for such matter.